# Unitofwork.dbcontext.savechanges not saving to database

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework

I have a method that I want to generate save capabilities for an API I have developed.  How do I properly save to my db?

The following 3 lines does not save quantityPicked and productIdPicked to my database based on my invocation of SaveChanges in ASP.NET Entity Framework.

```
namespace Services
{
    public interface IUnitOfWork : IDisposable
    {
        Data.SupplyWizardsContext DBContext();
        IGenericRepository<TEntity> GetRepository<TEntity>() where TEntity : class;
        void Dispose();
        void Save();
    }
}
public bool UpdateOrderPicks(int orderId, int orderItemId, int quantityPicked, int productIdPicked)
{
    var orderItem = orderItemRepository.Get(oi => oi.OrderID == orderId && oi.OrderItemID == orderItemId).FirstOrDefault();
    if (orderItem != null)
    {
        orderItem.PickedQuantity = quantityPicked;
        orderItem.ProductPickedId = productIdPicked;
        unitofwork.DBContext().SaveChanges();
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}

public override int SaveChanges()
{
    foreach (var history in this.ChangeTracker.Entries()
        .Where(e => e.Entity is IModificationHistory && e.State == EntityState.Added 
            || e.State == EntityState.Modified).Select(e => e.Entity as IModificationHistory))
    {
        if (history != null)
        {
            history.DateModified = DateTime.Now;

            if (history.DateCreated == DateTime.MinValue)
                history.DateCreated = DateTime.Now;
         }

    }

    int result = base.SaveChanges();

    return result;
 }



public IGenericRepository<TEntity> GetRepository<TEntity>() where TEntity : class
        {
            if (repositories.Keys.Contains(typeof(TEntity)))
                return repositories[typeof(TEntity)] as IGenericRepository<TEntity>;

            var repo = new GenericRepository<TEntity>(context);

            repositories.Add(typeof(TEntity), repo);

            return repo;
        }
```

How do I properly save quantityPicked/productIdPicked to the database using the 3rd line?

Comment: Could you post your model?

Comment: Where does `orderItem` come from?

Comment: It would be helpful to see more of your code so we can address the issue. You have very little code here so it is difficult to see what the issue is.

Comment: I was gauging how much to post so I will post more now.  Thank you for the feedback :).

Comment: More interestingly can be the method `DBContext()`.

Comment: Gladly!  Will post as well.

Comment: At what point is `orderItemRepository` related to `unitofwork`? Can you show your `unitofwork`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am going to go out on a limb and assume `orderItemRepository` is not actually related to your `unitofwork`.

Without seeing your `unitofWork` it's hard to say, however, ideally, you would have a property on your `unitofwork` for the repository.

You're also, so it seems, exposing the DbContext through your unitofwork - this can be a little dangerous in that you now no longer control access to the DBContext.

For example, and not 100% working code, but you will get the idea:

```
public class unitofWork(){

   private YourDBContext_dbContext = new YourDBContext_dbContext(); 

   public OrderItemRepository OrderItemRepository
   { 
     get
     {
       return _orderItemRepository ?? (_orderItemRepository = new OrderItemRepository(_dbContext));
     }
   }

   public void Save()
   {
            //your save logic save changes you want
            _dbContext.SaveChanges(); 
   }    
}
```

So you would then, in your coded, do something like:

```
var orderItem = unitofWork.OrderItemRepository.Get(oi => oi.OrderID == orderId && oi.OrderItemID == orderItemId).FirstOrDefault();
    if (orderItem != null)
    {
        orderItem.PickedQuantity = quantityPicked;
        orderItem.ProductPickedId = productIdPicked;
        unitofwork.DBContext().SaveChanges();
        return true;
    }
    return false;
```

Comment: Well, call me silly,  I completely missed the obvious feature that we always used LINQ in the past to generate queries.  So using the following definitely helped.  var orderItem = (from oi in unitofwork.DBContext().OrderItems where oi.OrderID == orderId && oi.OrderItemID == orderItemId select oi).FirstOrDefault();

Comment: That's a little  better though you're still not using a repository pattern. Might trip you up should you start adding unit tests etc.

Comment: Man,  this C# is very challenging.    Thank you for defining my method of choice.  Getting better at this however.   That is all that counts, right?   Moving forward each and every day.

Comment: That's all part of the game.  Every day is a learning day :-) no matter how long you have been doing this, there is always something to learn.